# Is it possible to crash a java decompiler with specific java code?

Tags: java, decompiling

As the title says, with only using Java code, so no bytecode, is it possible to crash most of the general java decompilers, let's say the ones you find by googling "java decompiler"?

I am aware that this will not stop people from building a specific decompiler that gets around the issue, but it will surely keep people away from simply decompiling files.

I was thinking along the lines of the following silly piece of code which I hope to never meet in production:

```
final public class X {
    //... interesting stuff

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return toString();
    }
}
```

This *could* be a possible counter measure against people wanting to print out your object, as an example.

Comment: So what happened when you tried this with these decompilers you mention?

Comment: @Dr.Avalanche That does not matter, the last piece of code is merely an example of a countermeasure about printing an object.

Comment: regardless of the proof of concept example, why not test your countermeasure theory?

Comment: Decompilers don't execute your code, so I don't think this is very likely. Maybe if you used some esoteric syntax from the latest java standard, the decompilers won't catch up for a while.

Comment: I doubt that you can "crash" a decompiler this way, except perhaps by simply tripping over an out-and-out bug.  I would imagine that a halfway decent decompiler will tolerate stuff it can't digest (since you get some awful looking obfuscated bytecodes).

Comment: You can (almost?) always use `javap` to see the byte code. Why would you try to hide something anyway? You will only raise the bar, but in the end there will be someone who will find out what you wanted to hide...

Comment: You certainly might be able to crash a debugger like that, but not a decompiler.

Comment: This answer seems impossible to answer, since anyone who would claim "no you can't" can't really prove it.

Comment: You're asking the wrong question. To accomplish your stated purpose you would need to guarantee that a specific piece of code, or several, would crash *all* known and future decompilers. And I don't see how you could possibly establish that. The specific countermeasure you mention shouldn't crash any correctly written decompiler, being trivial. You seem to think that a decompiler would execute the code. It won't.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the implementation. It might crash if they don't recognize the latest byte code instructions, and it might crash if they can't figure out what to decompile your byte code instructions to. However in my experience when decompilers cannot figure out what to decompile the byte code to they will simply dump the byte code that they can't figure out within the rest of the Java source code they have already decompiled. A suggestion to attempt to see this is to decompile programs written originally in another JVM language like Scala or Clojure.